# Separate convention from number so that I can run a formula that will convert mm to inches

Tags: python, python-3.x, literals, valueerror

I am learning python and I am having a hard time with a practice sheet where I am trying to convert millimeters to inches and vice versa. I am building it off a similar script that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius (and also vice versa).

Here's the script that converts F <-> C:

```
temp = input("Input the  temperature you like to convert? (e.g., 45F, 102C etc.) : ")
degree = int(temp[:-1])
i_convention = temp[-1]

if i_convention.upper() == "C":
  result = int(round((9 * degree) / 5 + 32))
  o_convention = "Fahrenheit"
elif i_convention.upper() == "F":
  result = int(round((degree - 32) * 5 / 9))
  o_convention = "Celsius"
else:
  print("Input proper convention.")
  quit()
print("The temperature in", o_convention, "is", result, "degrees.")
```

I wrote this, based on the one above:

```
meas = input("Convert mm to in and vice versa, enter a value (e.g. 10mm, 2in): \n")
num = int(meas[:-2])
i_measType = meas[-2]

if i_measType.upper() == "MM":
    result = int((num * (1/25.4)))
    o_measType = "in"
elif i_measType.upper() == "IN":
    result = int((num * 25.4))
    o_measType = "mm"
else:
    print("Input proper convention.")
    quit()
print(meas, " = ", result, o_measType)
```

I assume the problem is with the `[:-2]` and the `[-2]` because based on what I can understand, this part is used to maybe pull the convention from the number? I thought like if someone enters 44mm, `meas[:-2]` is used to convert that to 44 and the `meas[-2]` is mean to call the mm. But I am clearly wrong...

Any help and possibly explanation would be greatly appreciated.

The error is:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

Comment: You need `meas[-2:]` (`meas` from position `-2` to the end) to extract the "convention".

Comment: Where does `quit()` come from? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

meas[-2] is the 2nd to the last characters in the input string meas, in your case, it can either be 'm' or 'i'. It's a single character.

you can change your if/else conditions to 
if i_measType.upper() == "M" ...

or change your i_measType = [-2:]
to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I am just trying to understand this script so I am going to break it down to its basics and hopefully I can make sense of it.

```x = input("test")```
```y = int(x[-2:])```
```print(y)```

If the "input" is, say 10in, how do you isolate just the 10? When I run this I am getting:

```test15in```
```Traceback (most recent call last):```
```  File "/Users//Downloads/brackets.py", line 2, in <module>```
```    y = int(x[-2:])```
```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'in'```

Comment: @M.EricP. for s = "10in", s[:2] gives you "10". s[-2:] gives you "in" so your y = int(x[-2:]) is wrong because you are trying to convert string to int. you do not need this conversion based on your code because your if/else condition is testing if your y=="MM" or y=="IN"